# Compile some SCSS files to CSS (I am a beginner with Sass)

Tags: php, html, css, sass, gulp

I am currently new to Sass and my friend gave me a project that contained a Material Design 'template', that he made.

Unfortunately there is no .css file that got all the stylesheets in it.
There are a couple of .scss files though but I do not really know how to compile them all to a .css file.
I figured out that I could use 'gulp', but when I add all the files in the gulpfile.js to be compiled, it doesn't work.

I am wondering if someone could help me over Skype or something that I could share my screen and that someone could fix this for me.

[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm5GF.jpg) that there are many scss files and there are two folders with components and mixins. 
Some of the scss files also contain '@import' lines, but I do not know if I have to add those files in the gulpfile.

Here is a screenshot of the components folder:
[image: Screenshot]
I could not post a 3rd screenshot because of my reputation but the mixins folder contains the following files:

```
- _alerts.scss
- _buttons.scss
- _md-shadow.scss
- _placeholder.scss
```

I hope that someone could help me with this!

PS: It is in a Laravel project!

Thank you so much!

Kind regards,
smke

Comment: _"I am wondering if someone could help me over Skype or something"_ - SO is a Q&A site. That means that you ask a question here and get answers here. That's how your question and peoples answers can help other future visitors. Asking people to help you on Skype is off topic, since it's not helpful for anyone than just you. This is neither a place to ask developers to do your job for you.

Comment: Fist thing I'd suggest is to take a look at the [sass website](http://sass-lang.com/) and see if that brings you up to speed

Comment: I am sorry @MagnusEriksson, I just thought that it would be easier for us both. My bad, I would just like some help via here then :) Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @Dale I already did this, but I just can't get it to work. When I put all the scss files in the gulpfile.js it doesn't work either. :/

Comment: Go through some tutorials on Sass and Gulp, try something and if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back, show us what you've tried and we can take it from there. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scout-App easily with sass and you should create a scss file without undescore (_) to import other scss file with underscore. In Scout-App you have to select input folder that include directory with scss files and select output folder where you want to be css file export.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, there's a SCSS to CSS converter online. Just go to http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/ and copy the paste the code and press Compile. The CSS code will display below the button for you to copy and paste.

Comment: Can I so this with all the files? Since it is not just one file.

Comment: Yes. Although the best thing to do is to copy and paste all the code from all the files and it will then compile it into one for you.